# Tweet Using Javascript Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, twitter

I want to make a simple script to post a tweet from a Textbox when the user click on the Submit button, but all using Javascript, without any server-side language. How may I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.saschakimmel.com/2009/05/how-to-create-a-dynamic-tweet-this-button-with-javascript/
But just change the document.title to the location of your textbox

Comment: I think that even if the user is already logged in, he will see the Twitter page, I want to avoid this. Just like Tweet Button does, without showing the Twitter page it posts

Answer (score 7):

What you want to use is Twitter Anywhere, develop by twitter

http://dev.twitter.com/anywhere

This handles all OAuth, create the box and post the tweet.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, but first I need to know how to use OAuth and how to tweet using just Javascript/jQuery

Comment: Im not sure that you can do OAuth on client side javascript, even if you do it, you would share your API secret and you dont want to do that

Comment: It won't be shown because it's going to be a webapp for mobiles, so there is no problem with the API secret

Comment: FYI - Twitter Anywhere is dead. :(