# Automatically tweet file name of file opened with photoshop

Tags: javascript, twitter, photoshop

I'm new to programming, and have never done anything out side of web design stuff, so I'm not sure exactly how to go about actualizing a project idea I have.

For a gimmick twitter, I'd like to create a script that automatically tweets the file name every time I open an image in Photoshop. I'm using Windows 7 and Photoshop is my default image viewer.

Where do I start? I have the time and patience to learn whatever language.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking into Photoshop "ACTIONS". This is an area where you can create macros to record steps in photoshop, then repeat them all at once or in the fashion you program them.

Answer (score 0):

Actions are fine, but there are restrictive. You might want to consider learning JavaScript There are lots of resources available.

Your idea should be fairly straight forward; with once exception: There's no easy way to check to see when a new document has been opened. You can run a script to find out this information, but having a script that runs in the "background" waiting for a new document to pop up isn't so easy. So the "automatic" part of your idea may prove difficult. However it would be fairly straight-forward to write a script to tweet the name of the document which could be run by an action or a keyboard shortcut.

I'll help you out with a simple script:

```
// We create a variable called srcDoc
// which is a shortcut to the active document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

// We assaign a variable to the active document's name
myFileName = app.activeDocument.name;

// we display the active name
alert(myFileName)
```

If you save that file as myfirstscript.jsx . Open up photoshop and run the script (File..>Scripts..>Browse..>myfirstscript.jsx) The above script will tell you what file you're working on.

The script is flawed as it doesn't take into account the situation of NOT having any documents open. So we just add an if statement:

```
if (documents.length != 0) 
{
    // We create a variable called srcDoc
    // which is a shortcut to the active document
    var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

    // We assaign a variable to the active document's name
    myFileName = app.activeDocument.name;

    // we display the active name
    alert(myFileName)
}
else alert("No documents open, dude!")
```

It's a start and I'm sure other people will help you out with the Twitter part - which is the hard part.

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641495/tweet-using-javascript-only) as well. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks. Poked around a bit and in Photoshop / File / Scripts / Script Events Manager you can set it to run scripts on different events, like saving, opening the app, or opening a file with the app.

Still figuring out how to tweet what it returns though.